# drupal_mail() new line \n not working

Tags: emails

I'm trying to insert a new line in message body using \n but it's not working.
Tried already with \r\n and it doesn't work also.

Any help?

Tks.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Could be a couple things, without seeing any of your code it's difficult to help you.

Try:

1. Making sure you're using double quotes (`"`) instead of single quotes (`'`) around the new line characters. (This is because PHP does not interpolate strings defined by single quotes).
2. Setting the Content-Type to `text/plain` in the mail headers. (If you need HTML in your email, use `<br />` for new lines).

Also, you should always use `\r\n` with emails so the new line is recognized across all platforms.

Answer (score 1):

Are using double quotes? They are necessary for the special characters to be interpreted correctly.